# Break points not working debbuing golang in VScode

Tags: macos, go, debugging, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I have a problem when debugging a project which is done in golang, the project compiles correctly and runs perfectly, however when I add a break point, the console returns the following error. **I am not using rosetta.**

I also managed to reproduce the same problem with GoLand (IDE JetBrains)

[image]

If I remove the break point and continue with the process, the project continues to run without errors. The problem is when VScode finds the break point.

Im using **macOS Big Sur version 11.3 (20E232)**

#### What version of Go im using (`go version`)?

```
    $ go version go1.16.3 darwin/arm64
```

#### What operating system and processor architecture im using (`go env`)?

`go env` Output

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/thomascaycedomartinez/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/thomascaycedomartinez/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/thomascaycedomartinez/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/thomascaycedomartinez/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/2x/7xq8cphj5gzc5lq2fbbl3vtw0000gn/T/go-build3536386239=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

#### launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "kuenta backend",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/kuenta",
            "env": {
                "HOSTNAME": "localhost"
            },
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

The break points should work, correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, in short, this is an issue that apparently occurs with the latest update in macOS Big Sur 11.3 (20E232)

To partially solve this problem until fixed.

- You need to clone the dlv repository and add the following code block[image: 1]
- Rebuild and copy dlv to temp path.
- Go to goland and select `Edit Custom Propierties`
  [image: 1]
- Add the path to delve on a new line in my case `dlv.path=/Users/thomascaycedomartinez/go/bin/dlv`
  [image: 4]
- Save the file and now you can debug normaly.
- To see more information you can visit this issue https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2436